# Can't run Spring Boot app from Command Prompt

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

[image]

This is my project structure. I created executable jar file of this Spring boot app. When i try to run it from Command Prompt i get this error :

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/tiles.xml] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getURL(ServletContextResource.java:156) ~[spring-web-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is due to Regression Error In Spring Boot 1.4.3 with Fat Jar packaging.
Refer to this for a solution:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8291

Comment: i added <executions>
     <execution>
      <goals>
       <goal>repackage</goal>
      </goals>
     </execution>
    </executions> 
but still the same problem

Answer (score 1):

if I'm correct, you're dealing with JSPs. Ideally, the packaging should be WAR instead of JAR. Try packaging the project as a WAR and then try to run the same.